# Grails 2.0.0M1 and WebFlow

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

Can anyone confirm that the webflow plugin is working in 2.0.0M1? I've installed the plugin but my "*Flow" actions don't seem to be treated differently then my other actions. I've additionally tried rebuilding grails-core from GitHib (2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) and the behavior is the same.

Here's the action in question:

```
 def baselineFlow() {

    showQuestion {
        on("checkout").to "enterPersonalDetails"
        on("continueShopping").to "displayCatalogue"
    }

}
```

When I go to controllerName/baseline it acts as if baseline.gsp isn't there (404 on controllerName/baseline) as opposed to trying to resolve baseline/showQuestion.gsp  I do have a controllerName/baseline/showQuestion.gsp in place in views. The same action works in 1.3.7.

Comment: Can you post the webflow code and explain why you think it's not working, i.e. what behaviour are you observing and what are you expecting?

Comment: Thanks Don, editing the question with the action code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug. I suggest you create an issue in the [Grails bug tracker](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS). Attach your application to the issue and provide instructions for reproducing the error. In my experience, the Grails team are very good at resolving reported bugs. If you do it now, it should be fixed for the final release of 2.0.0